# Convert full time string to Unix timestamp in jQuery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix

I need to produce a timestamp of each date/time string that gets produced in a foreach loop.

How do I turn this string `Mon Aug 08 2016 10:09:42 GMT+0100 (BST)` into a Unix Timestamp for comparison?

I am then going to use that single value to do a jQuery sort (code below)

```
var boards = $(".socialBox");

boards.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return $(a).data("date") - $(b).data("date");
});

$("#social-board").html(boards);
```

As you can imagine the above code doesn't work on the current date/time string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`new Date('Mon Aug 08 2016 10:09:42 GMT+0100 (BST)').getTime();`

The `getTime()` function returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string data to date object along with `.getTime()` to get number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01:

```
boards.sort(function(a, b){ 
  return new Date($(a).data("date")).getTime() - new Date($(b).data("date")).getTime();
});
```